# How to share common code among multiple activities? Please, this is not a repeated question

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-studio, google-cloud-firestore

Actually I'm trying to create an app it has Navigation Drawer and Google Sign In for which I also need to add auth code every where.

I wanted to know is there any way of putting all the navigation drawer code somewhere else (say in different class file) and then calling the code in the different activities?

As copy pasting the same thing again and again is sometime irritating.

Please help.

Thanks.

Comment: maybe make util class of auth and get your auth instance from there, by this you can use it anywhere by importing authUtil or you can also use inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can do it very simply.**

But this is not a `good approach` that you `sign in with google` in every item of navigation drawer. If you `sign in user on first screen` and then `access that user` wherever you want without doing unwanted things in code.

**But Still you want solution**

> Solution

you should make a `google sign in method` in a class with parameter Context. Access it wherever you want from that class provides `sign in method`.

**Library**

you can do it very simply by library from github:

[Google Sign in library](https://github.com/pchmn/RxSocialAuth)

Answer (score 0):

The process is simple, create classes and pass the data as a parameter